# Sync GeoJson to cartoDB?

Tags: carto, geojson

Is there a way to sync GeoJSON files to my cartoDB table?

If this is not yet supported, what would be the best way of implementing this feature (syncing the data frequently with the existing cartoDB table) myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be worthwhile looking at the CartoDB Import API. You can set up syncing a file from a URL with a simple cURL command.

Check out the documentation and the example at this [link](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/import-api/sync-tables/#syncing-a-file-from-a-url). It may help get you started down the right track.

**OR**

While the import API is one possible method, it looks like you can sync GeoJSON if it is hosted on the web somewhere. This method was outlined on the Fulcrum guides and can be seen [here](http://www.fulcrumapp.com/guides/publishing-data/cartodb/), read the section "Creating A Synced CartoDB Table".

Steps are as follows.

1. In cartodb connect a datafile using a URL as shown below.

[image]

2. Set the update frequency as shown below.

[image]

I used GeoJSON from Mapbox to test and can be found here `http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.o11ipb8h/markers.geojson`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already have a premium account. I wanted to check if CartoDB supports geoJSON syncing because I don't see that data type specified anywhere.

Comment: @IreneL I just added an additional method which may (fingers crossed) help you out.